# Hive table populating null as ""

Tags: apache-spark, hive

I am trying to populate a table with csv file format. The null values are getting replace as empty string.

Can anyone please help me to fix this, I want to populate null value as null

Below is a piece of code :

`spark-sql> directory insert overwrite /temp/t1_csv as select * FROM db.test123 ORDER BY id using csv with options(delimiter=|, coalesce=1);`

`hdfs dfs -get /temp/t1_csv/part-00000* .`

```
zcat part-00000-*.gz
1001|501|ABCD|
1002|501||XYZ
```

Expected:

```
zcat part-00000-*.gz
1001|501|ABCD|null
1002|501|null|XYZ
```

Answer (score 1):

I think that you may try to create a table before insert and set serialization.null.format"="" property. Without this empty values are not going to be treated as nulls during write

You can find more details in this [helpful blogpost Published by swatigirhepunje](https://studywithswati.wordpress.com/2020/06/30/hive-table-properties-null-format/)

Comment: I have added these table properties. "serialization.null.format"="" and "serialization.format"=""

Comment: i am not sure if you should change serialization.format